# How to handle non-standard constructors in case of double inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, base-class

I would like to inherit a class `C` from two classes, `A` and `B`, one of which (`B`) has a non-standard constructor. How should the constructor of `C` look to be compatible with either of the two base classes?
I have a little example that demonstrates my problem and it looks like this:

```
class A {
    public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
};

class B {
    public:
    B(int abc,
      int def,
      int ghj){}
      ~B(){}
};

class C:public B, public A {
    public:
    C(int test,
      int test2,
      int test3){}
    ~C(){}
};

int main(void) {
    C* ptr = new C (123,456,789);
}
```

Where I get the following compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'C::C(int, int, int)':
main.cpp:19:17: error: no matching function for call to 'B::B()'
       int test3){}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the current implementation of `C`'s constructor, the base subobject of `B` (and `A`) will be default-initialized, but class `B` doesn't have default constructor, which causes the error.

You could apply [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize `B` base subobject via appropriate constructor of `B`. e.g.

```
class C:public B, public A {
    public:
    C(int test,
      int test2,
      int test3) : B(test, test2, test3) {}
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ~C(){}
};
```